# Selection Sort: After how many passes does the list becomes sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

While studying for an upcoming test I found this question:

1. Our sorting code completes all passes of the algorithm, even if the list becomes sorted before
   the last pass. After how many passes of the selection sort algorithm on the list `[9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1]`
   could we stop because the list has become sorted?

Using my understanding from the `Selection Sort Algorithm` my answer would be `7`:

```
[9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1]
[9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1]
[8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1]
[6, 8, 9, 4, 3, 1]
[4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1]
[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

But according to my instructor after `3` passes my list would be sorted. What am I doing wrong? This is just a multiple choice question without any background but the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step should be finding the smallest number in the array(1) from you current element(9) and switching their positions, second step should be finding next smallest element(3) and switching it with the next element in array(8), and so on. This algorithm works by making comparisons to all elements in the array that haven't been sorted already hence why the run time is worst case O(n^2).

Will look like:    [9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1],[1, 8, 6, 4, 3, 9],[1, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9],[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]

Here is also a good exapmle of selection sort in [action](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/selection-sort/tutorial/)

Comment: For a reason I was applying `Insertion Sort`, you're right